# Change css style of a div based on the value from array

Tags: php, css, fullcalendar

I have tried various methods from answers here on Stackoverflow, but none seems to help.

I have added hall_no on my fullcalendar, and hall_no has three options,

1. Hall A
2. Hall B
3. Hall A+B.

I want to change the (.fc-event) div's background color based on the values from hall_no.

```
$data_events = array();

 foreach($events->result() as $r) {

     $data_events[] = array(
         "id" => $r->id,
         "title" => $r->name . "\n" . "\n" . $r->hall_no,
         "end" => $r->end,
         "start" => $r->start
     );
 }

 echo json_encode(array("events" => $data_events));
 exit();
 }

public function halla(){
    if (isset($_GET['hall_no'])){
        $query = $_GET['hall_no'];
    }else{
        $query = NULL;
    }
}

public function hallb(){
    if ($query == 'Hall A'){
            "<style>
                .fc-event{background-color:#00cc00;}
            </style>"
    }elseif ($query == 'Hall B'){
            "<style>
                .fc-event{background-color:#ff1a8c;}
            </style>"
    }else{
            "<style>
                .fc-event{background-color:#00ffff;}
            </style>"
    }
}
```

I have also tried the in_array() function:

```
$data_events = array();

 foreach($events->result() as $r) {

     $data_events[] = array(
         "id" => $r->id,
         "title" => $r->name . "\n" . "\n" . $r->hall_no,
         "end" => $r->end,
         "start" => $r->start
     );
 }

 echo json_encode(array("events" => $data_events));
 exit();
 }

if (in_array("Hall A", $data_events))
      {
      "style=.fc-event{background-color:#00cc00} ";
      }
    elseif (in_array("Hall B", $data_events))
      {
      "style=.fc-event{background-color:#ff1a8c} ";
      }
    else
      {
      "style=.fc-event{background-color:#00ffff} ";
      }
```

Comment: have a look at `strcmp` and the `echo` function, etc

Comment: Echo can be very useful @Temani especially if you want to output something. :-) OP do you have errors turned off? That code can't run in PHP without errors.

Comment: And you have an exit(); before the if(), maybe you should delete that? And there is one `}` too much in the code

Comment: @Andreas `if you want to output something` --> which is the case, he need to at least print these style to his page, so we should have an echo or a return somewhere ;)

Comment: I just placed my if() before the exit(), but still the colors won't change. Neither there are any errors in the console.

Comment: Yep see that too. And that is why I say also he must have errors turned off. There is no way this code can compile.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok let me see about that.

Comment: No errors? Huh? Really? https://3v4l.org/jnmKn

Comment: @Andreas Don't worry about the extra `}` that you see. I did not post the whole calendar code. Sorry about that.

Comment: It doesn't matter there are more errors. To say that there are no errors is complete bull....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fullcalendar actually has a feature to support you in doing this by setting a property on your event. Then fullCalendar will handle setting the colour on the resulting HTML element automatically.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object - you can choose from either:

> "color":  Sets an event's background and border color

or

> "backgroundColor":    Sets an event's background color

So you can simply do something like this:

```
foreach($events->result() as $r) {
    $color = "";
    switch ($r->hall_no) {
      case "Hall A":
        $color = "#00cc00";
        break;
      case "Hall B":
        $color = "#ff1a8c";
        break;
      default:
        $color = "#00ffff";
        break;
    }

    $data_events[] = array(
      "id" => $r->id,
      "title" => $r->name . "\n" . "\n" . $r->hall_no,
      "end" => $r->end,
      "start" => $r->start,
      "color" => $color
    );
}
```

Now each event will be coloured according to the "Hall_no" value associated with it.

P.S. your solution based on writing `<style>` elements wouldn't ever work because those rules based on the "fc-event" class will affect *all* event elements, since they all carry that class, and not just the ones which have that particular data value.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I tried all the various styling methods, but none worked like you said. Cheers.

Comment: No problem. It's always worth studying the fullCalendar documentation in detail when faced with something like this, it does have a lot of features.

Comment: Indeed it does. I'll keep in mind to read the documentations. God bless.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't echo the style you are applying through php.

```
echo "style=.fc-event{background-color:#00cc00} ";
```

Comment: Added echo. No errors in the console, and my events just disappeared from the calendar.

Comment: this would just echo this output directly, out of context, as part of what is otherwise a JSON response, thus causing the JSON to be invalid. I don't think you thought this answer through. If the code was producing HTML elements it might achieve something if injected into the correct place in the markup but a) the code is generating JSON not HTML and b) it's not even a valid style attribute anyway.